# Undo all changes of one of the file among multiple committed files

Tags: git

I cut a branch `my_branch` from `develop` and updated 4 files.

I committed and pushed the changes several times.

Now I have to revert all changes from file2 amongst the four files and bring file2 into a state that is exactly same as it was when `my_branch` was cut from `develop` branch.

I tried

```
git reset HEAD file2
git checkout -- file2
```

But that did not work.

How may I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout `file2` to origin's `develop` branch.

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git checkout my_branch

$ git checkout origin/develop file2
```

Comment: Thanks @Sajib Khan - this solves the problem - very simple indeed

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify commit from which you'd like get `file2`:

```
git checkout HEAD^^^^ -- file2
```

Command above will checkut `file2` from 4 commits back.